# Icon design etymology?

Tags: icon, design-principles, design-process, history

Is anyone aware of any resources for Icon design etymology, or the history of icon design? I'm talking about icons like Wi-Fi/Ethernet/Bluetooth status indicators, add, save, and similar simple images explaining actions or status. Like you might find in the Glyphicon set, for example.

We're working on a project and trying to come up with useful or novel illustrations for some non-standard actions, and in some cases there aren't any decent examples to use as inspiration. The idea came up that if there's a good anthology or even articles on icon history, it would be useful as a reference for the design process. As an example, the Wikipedia page for Bluetooth (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) explains the history and design of that icon well and clearly.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but that'd be a great idea for a blog...research the history of common icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I cannot help for recent icons but for the historical part of your question, I have given a brief presentation about the history of pictograms before. Obviously, starting at the Egyptians may be a bit of a long shot depending on what you are trying to accomplish. I'd advise looking at [the work of Gerd Arntz](http://www.gerdarntz.org/isotype) as a starting point.

Gerd Arntz was working on Isotype. Isotype was founded by Otto Neurath and from what I recall was used in a museum in order to communicate information to people who were illiterate.

Other leads include [Blissymbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blissymbols), a pictogram language still used nowadays for children with disabilities and the [Olympic pictograms](http://1stmuse.com/pictograms/).

EDIT: Here are the references I had used to build a presentation in 2011, hopefully everything still works :-)

- Fletcher, Alan. *The Art of Looking Sideways*. Phaidon, 2001. 1064p.
- Hollis, Richard. *Le graphisme au XXe siècle*. Thames & Hudson, 1997.
  224p.
- Lupton, Ellen. Miller, Abbott. *Design Writing Research : Writing on
  Graphic Design*. Phaidon, 1999. 211p.
- Icons for the People. *Eye Magazine*. No. 78, Winter 2010. p. 62-67.
- Dreyfuss, Henry. *Symbol Sourcebook: An Authoritative Guide to
  International Graphic Symbols*. McGraw-Hill, 1984. 288 p.
- Wikipedia. *Hiéroglype égyptien*. [Online]. URL :
  [http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiéroglyphe_égyptien](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hi%C3%A9roglyphe_%C3%A9gyptien) (retrieved September 7th 2011)
- Rosa, Carlos. *40 years of pictograms in universal contexts : what’s
  next?* [Online]. URL:
  http://www.scribd.com/doc/36297922/40-years-of-Pictograms-in-Universal-Contexts-What-s-next
  (retrieved August 22nd 2011)
- Under Consideration. *Otl Aicher: An Expanded, Abridged Story*, [Online]. URL:
  http://www.underconsideration.com/speakup/archives/004931.html
  (retrieved August 22nd 2011)
- History of Graphic Design. *Symbols : The Alphabet of Human Thought.*
  [Online]. URL: http://designhistory.org/symbols.html (retrieved
  August 22nd 2011)
- Gerd Arntz Web Archive. *Gerd Arntz (1900-1988)*, [Online]. URL:
  http://gerdarntz.org/content/gerd-arntz (retrieved August 22nd 2011)
- Form Fifty Five. *Glasgow 2014 Pictograms*. [Online]. URL:
  http://www.formfiftyfive.com/2011/07/glasgow-2014-pictograms/
  (retrieved August 22nd 2011)
- PATTON, Phil. *Neurath, Bliss and the Language of the Pictogram*,
  [Online]. URL:
  http://www.aiga.org/neurath-bliss-and-the-language-of-the-pictogram/
  (retrieved August 24th 2011)
- Burke, Christopher. *Isotype : Representing Social Facts
  Pictorially*. [Online]. URL:
  http://www.isotyperevisited.org/Isotype_representing_social_facts_pictorially.pdf
  (retrieved August 24th 2011)
- Idsgn. *The Helvetica Man*, [Online]. URL:
  http://idsgn.org/posts/the-helvetica-man/ (retrieved August 24th 2011)